# Login mandatory for using my store

Tags: magento-1.7, login, magento-community, home-page

I have a store using Magento 1.7 and I need to set a login/registration page as the first page that is shown before buying anything, so that it is mandatory to log in.

I edited `cms.xml`, under `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/cms.xml`, and managed to show login/registration in the homepage:

```
<cms_page translate="label">
    <label>CMS Pages (All)</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="page_content_heading" template="cms/content_heading.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="cms.wrapper" translate="label">
            <label>CMS Content Wrapper</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>std</value></action>
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/>
            <block type="cms/page" name="cms_page"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```

I also added a line in `customer.xml` under `design/frontend/default/custom_theme/layout/customer.xml` for removing the login/registration boxes after customer login, so that it looks like:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <remove name="customer_form_login"></remove>
(...)
```

But I still can navigate through all the contents of my store without loging in; how should I do in order that the first page only contains login/registration? I think that is something related to layouts and phtml, but I am a bit confused and don't know which file I should edit or if I should include some other files.

Any help is much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can redirect your customer (not logged in ) to login page. you can achieve this by event observer.

Follow below steps to create custom module

Create File with name `Namespace_Module.xml` at location `app/etc/modules/` with code

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Namespace_Module>
      <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Namespace_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**create** `config.xml` **at** `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc` **directory and add the following xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
            </namespace_module>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </namespace_module>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module>
                        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkForLogin</method>
                    </namespace_module>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**Create a Observer.php in your Module’s Model/ directory with below code**

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object{

public function checkForLogin(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $allow = array('customer_account_login','customer_account_createpost','customer_account_create','customer_account_forgotpassword','customer_account_resetpassword','customer_account_loginpost','customer_account_forgotpasswordpost','customer_account_resetpasswordpost');
   if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && !in_array(strtolower($observer->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName()),$allow) ) {
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'))->sendResponse();
   exit;
   }
 }
}
```

Create file `Data.php` at `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/` with code

```
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: Where exactly should I add this code? I mean I guess there is a module for login in Magento, but I am not sure. I see that there is customer in the core code. Sorry I quite new to Magento and still don't know about it enough

Comment: Do not edit core files, create a new custom module

Comment: Yes, actually that's what I tried. I created a new module with the two files you say. I also added the corresponding xml in app/etc/modules, and I can see from admin->System->Advanced->Advanced that the module is active. But I can't see any effects, it doesn't seem to work. Is this the proper way to proceed?

Comment: please check my updated answer , you can create whole custom module with that

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar situation here...we need people to sign in before they buy, but instead of blocking their access to the website, we just hide the price if the customer is not logged in yet.

This was a better solution for us because customer can see which products we have, what promotions are going on, etc...and then when they want to buy, they need to sign in and just after that the "Add To Cart" button shows up.

We use this extension, but you could use any other option: https://amasty.com/magento-hide-price.html