# Prohibition of purchase for non login users

Tags: magento-1.9

I added my store. Also I created new group of users(Agent). And I would like, that all users who have not logged in as agents could not purchase products. How can I do it?

Comment: you can disable guest checkout from admin

Comment: @Piyush can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes you can do it programmatically also  [check this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/151149/20064)

Comment: You mean with user (Agent) a Customer Group? And You want to block all other Group from the purchase?

Comment: @Marcel I have only Agent, but if u non login u can't buy anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable guest checkout in System>Configuration>Sales>Checkout>Checkout Options
[image]